# How do you load images into specific spots based on a list and a dictionary?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a simple 2d exploration game in replit (hoping to have a nice base for a future game I'm making) and I have all my map tiles as images

```py
WATER = pygame.image.load(r'water.jpg')
SAND = pygame.image.load(r'sand.jpg')
GRASS = pygame.image.load(r'grass.jpg')
FOREST = pygame.image.load(r'Forest.jpg')
VILLAGE = pygame.image.load(r'village.jpg')
```

and I have my dictionary which compresses them into a single letter

```py
TileMap = {'W': WATER, 'S': SAND, 'G': GRASS, 'F': FOREST, 'V': VILLAGE }
```

and I have my map which should usually come up with the image after the code:

```py
map1 = ["WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
        "WWWWWWWWWGGGWWWWWWWWWWW",
        "WWWWWGGGGGGGGGGGWWWWWWW", 
        "WWWWGGGGGFFFGGGGGVWWWWW",
        "WWWGGGGGFFFFFFGGGGGWWWW", 
        "WWWGGGGGGFFFFFGGGGGGWWW",
        "WWGGGGGGGGGFFGGGGGGGWWW", 
        "WWGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGWW",
        "WWGGGGGGSSSSSSSGGGGGGGW", 
        "WWGGGGSSSSSSSSSSGGGGGGW",
        "WGGGGGGGSSGGGGGGGGGGGSW", 
        "WGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGSSW",
        "WSGGGGGGGGFFGGGGGGGGSSW", 
        "WSSGGGGGGFFFGGGGGFFGGSW",
        "WSSGGGGGFFFFFFGGFFFFFGW", 
        "WSGGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGW",
        "WWGGGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFGGWW", 
        "WWGGGGGGGFFFFFFFFGGGWWW",
        "WWWWGGGGGGGGFFGGGGGWWWW", 
        "WWWWWWSSSSSGGGGSSSWWWWW",
        "WWWWWWWWWSSSSSSSSWWWWWW", 
        "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWSWWWWWWWW",
        "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"
        ]
```

[image]

and I have a attempt at showing the images

```py
pygame.image.load_basic(TileMap(map1))
```

and I get this error message:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.12)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py",line 74, in <module>
    pygame.image,load_basic(TileMap(map1))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
>>>
```

does anyone have any suggestions as to how to make this work?
here is the link to the replit code: [my game](https://replit.com/@Mythunrun/Forgotten-prophesy?v=1)

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do exactly, but I can tell you that `TileMap` is a dictionary, and you cannot call() a dictionary with parenthesis after it like you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WATER`, `SAND`, etc are already `pygame.Surface` objects. You do not need to load them again. Just [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the images:

```py
# application loop
while run:
    # [...]

    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        for col in range(MAPWIDTH):
            c = map1[row][col]
            image = TileMap[c]
            x = col * TILESIZE
            y = row * TILESIZE
            DISPLAY.blit(image, (x, y))

    # [...]
```

(The code is based on the code in your previous question: [how do you make the map more detailed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72665540/how-do-you-make-the-map-more-detailed))

Comment: I added that. my code no longer has the error message, but nothing is showing up on the thing

Comment: @roarg Do you call `pygame.display.update()`?